# use stripe or paypal to send money to accounts

Tags: node.js, paypal, stripe-payments, payment

I am using `stripe` for my app that I've developed in `node.js`. The way the app is set up is that the merchant (selling their service) will be selling their service to the clients at a `variable` rate each month (calculated by my app). So what I need to do all through my app is enable my app to automatically charge the client (like a subscription) but at a variable rate (so I guess like a stripe `charge`. Then what I need to do is instead of paying me, I need to go directly to the merchant (which will all have stripe accounts programmatically set up by me).

My situation feels a little bit unique, and after doing some reasearch I am not even sure if something like this is posisble, becuase I am essentially eliminating the middle man (me) in this situation and going directly from the consumer to the merchant. Could someone point me into the right direction in terms of `docs` to do this, or provide me with some advice, maybe use paypal instead?

Comment: You can take a look at Stripe Connect - https://stripe.com/docs/connect. You'd likely want to reach out to Support for more detailed advice : https://support.stripe.com/contact/

Comment: you need to run a cron job with a frequency at which you want the oepration to repeat, and add an intent in the database. Once that's added, it can be reflected in user's dashboard / user can be communicated via email / sms / whatever to continue the payment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.